# I deny my admin overall permission in jenkins and need it back

Tags: security, jenkins, admin

I denied my admin overall permissions in jenkins and I can't configure it anymore.

I've tried everything [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disable+security) but nothing worked.

After changing `<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>` to `<useSecurity>false</useSecurity>` I can open jenkins with my job, but when I  want to configure security again, and set logins, everything come back.

It happened because of Matrix-based security plugin I set before, I think I set settings for anonymous (as was written in plugin table), but it sets on admin.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have access to the machine running the jenkins?

Comment: @Jayan he seems to have access because it looks like he edited the configuration manually. But I'd also like to know if he restarted Jenkins after that change.